# Why is the worst case time complexity of this simple algorithm T(n/2) +1 as opposed to n^2+T(n-1)?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

[image]

The following question was on a recent assignment in University. I would have thought the answer would be n^2+T(n-1) as I thought the n^2 would make it's asymptotic time complexity O(n^2). Where as with T(n/2)+1 its asymptotic time complexity would be O(log2(n)).

The answers were returned and it turns out the correct answer is T(n/2)+1 however I can't get my head around why this is the case.

Could someone possibly explain to me why that's the worst case time complexity of this algorithm? It's possible my understanding of time complexity is just wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asymptotic time complexity is taking `n` large. In the case of your example, since the question specifies that `k` is fixed, the only complexity relevant is the last one. See the [Wikipedia formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), specifically:

[image]

As `n` grows to infinity, the recursion that dominates `T(n) = T(n / 2) + 1`. You can prove this as well using the formal definition, basically picking `x_0 = 10 * k` and showing that a finite `M` can be found using the first two cases. It should be clear that both `log(n)` and `n^2` satisfy the definition, so the tighter bound is the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Thanks! Is it  possible you could elaborate slightly on why k being fixed means that the only relevant complexity is the last one? I read the formal definitions on the wiki but I'm still don't really understand why this statement is true.

Comment: If `k` is not fixed, then you can choose an `x_0 = 10 * k`, which yields a finite `M` satisfying the definition. If `k` isn't fixed, then such an `x_0` may not exist because `k` can always be "chosen" by an adversary to be larger, therefore the a finite `M` cannot necessarily be found.

Answer (score 1):

What does O (f (n)) mean? It means the time is at most c * f (n), for some unknown and possibly large c.

kevmo claimed a complexity of O (log2 n). Well, you can check all the values n ≤ 10k, and let the largest value of T (n) be X. X might be quite large (about 167 k^3 in this case, I think, but it doesn't actually matter). For larger n, the time needed is at most X + log2 (n). Choose c = X, and this is always less than c * log2 (n).

Of course people usually assume that a O (log n) algorithm would be quick, and this one most certainly isn't if say k = 10,000. So you learned as well that O notation must be handled with care.